# Prove that the coding $\pi_k$ is effective

Tags: computability

I have to prove that the coding $\pi_k$ is effective given that $\pi_k$ is a surjective coding of $\mathbf N^k$ and $\pi_k$ is a recursive function.

What I've got:

A coding by definition is an injective function from a set $X$ to $\mathbf N$. 
I know by definition that a coding $\pi_k$ is effective if it is recursive and there exist decoding functions $J_0^k, ..., J_k^k$ for which $J_i^k=x_i$ in $(x_0, ..., x_k)$ and which are also recursive functions.

How can I find such functions or prove they exist?

Answer (score 1):

Since $\pi_k$ is bijective, for every $x∈N$, there exists a unique tuple $(x_1, ..., x_k)∈N^k$ such that $\pi_k(x_1,...,x_n) = x$. So, how can we define $J^k_i$ ? A solution would be to use a coding that is already known to be effective, let $\alpha_k$ be that effective coding and $\beta^k_1,..., \beta^k_k$ the associated decoding functions. Let $x∈N$, we can put : $$J^k_i(x) = \beta_i^k(\mu y(\ \pi_k(\ \beta^k_1(y)\ , ...,\ \beta^k_k(y)) = x))$$

For $\alpha_k$, we can take the [cantor tuple function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function), which is known to be primitive recursive.

Of course, that's not a proper definition, we need mathematical induction to throw away those horrible dots.

Comment: Well, in the book I'm studying from the definition of coding is an injective function from a set to $\mathbf N$

Comment: You said in your post that $\pi_k$ is surjective, you haven't indicated that it was injective so i assumed that it is not. If it is, i'll edit my answer.

Comment: Yes, just clarifying that it further eases the proof. 

OK, so in proving that the coding is effective we use a coding that is already known to be effective. Isn't this like recursive reasoning?

Comment: No it is not, because we have an independent proof that tells us $\alpha_k$ is an effective coding.